# Add constraint to compare two attributes of different tables?

Tags: sql, constraints

Here are my tables. I need to check that the 'program' attribute referenced in StudentsBranch with the table Students and the table Branches is the same. How can I do it?

```
 CREATE TABLE Programmes (
    name            VARCHAR(200)   UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Programmes PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE Students (
    id              NUMERIC(10,0)  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Students PRIMARY KEY (idnr),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programmes(name)
);

CREATE TABLE Branches (
    name            VARCHAR(200)   UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Branches PRIMARY KEY (name, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programmes(name)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentsBranch (
    student         NUMERIC(10,0)  NOT NULL,
    program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    branch          VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_StudentsBranch PRIMARY KEY (student),
    /* Below how the foreign keys I think should be  */
    FOREIGN KEY (student, program) REFERENCES Students(idnr, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches(name, program)
    /* I need to add a constraint to verify that the 'program' in Students
     * and the 'program' in Branches are equivalent. How?
    */
);
```

Comment: What issue are you having with those constraints? Have you tested inserting data that should be restricted?

Comment: I would add something like `CHECK (Students.program = Branches.program)` correct? In this case I would have the following error, though:  "ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "students""

Comment: No. A `CHECK` will not work here. I'm asking if you have tested the solution you have right now? As is, you will not get a `program` that does not belong to a branch or a student - it would need to exist for both. I think that is what you are wanting - correct? If so, your solution should work. Either way - why not test it out?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to have an numeric column of primary key and have primary key for every table. 
Once you have primary key for every table you can referece primary key of a specific table and refere it as foerign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Programmes (
ID          INT,
name        VARCHAR(200)   UNIQUE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Programmes PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE  Students(
id              INT,
ProgrammID  INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Students PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ProgrammID) REFERENCES Programmes(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Branches (
BranchID        INT,
ProgrammID  INT NOT NULL,
name            VARCHAR(200)   UNIQUE NOT NULL,
--program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_Branches PRIMARY KEY (BranchID, ProgrammID),
FOREIGN KEY (ProgrammID) REFERENCES Programmes(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentsBranch (
StudentsBranchID    INT,
studentID           INT  NOT NULL,
ProgrammID          INT   NOT NULL,
BranchID            INT   NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_StudentsBranch PRIMARY KEY (StudentsBranchID),
FOREIGN KEY (ProgrammID) REFERENCES Programmes(id),
FOREIGN KEY (studentID) REFERENCES Students(id),
FOREIGN KEY (BranchID, ProgrammID) REFERENCES Branches(BranchID, ProgrammID)

);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write that constraint with that existing database model you have now.

The only way I see you could do it, is by changing the primary key of `Students` to (`id`, `program`):

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    id              NUMERIC(10,0)  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Students PRIMARY KEY (id, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programmes(name)
);
```

Then the table `StudentsBranch` could naturally enforce both FKs with using the **single** column `program`, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentsBranch (
    student         NUMERIC(10,0)  NOT NULL,
    program         VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    branch          VARCHAR(200)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_StudentsBranch PRIMARY KEY (student),
    FOREIGN KEY (student, program) REFERENCES Students (id, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches (name, program)
);
```